# Exception in HttpResponse execute in android

Tags: java, android, json, exception, http-request

I'm stuck for hours with an Exception from HttpRequest method and I'm really tired of this. Did a google research, but i can't find any answer to fix it. I need to do a http request to get data from database via PHP scripts. Everything is going well, when I call method for all lines from table with params:

> url - "http://android-connection.cba.pl/get_all_notes.php" method -
>   "GET" List - empty list

But it spits out an Exception when i trying to get specify id line with parameters:

> url - "http://android-connection.cba.pl/get_note.php" method - "GET"
>   List - [noteid=1]

I call it from doInBackground method in class, which extends AsyncTask.
There is this problematic method, if you could help me with this.. thanks!

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.e("URL", url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

and there are logs:

```
05-06 08:50:35.647: D/AndroidRuntime(3119): Shutting down VM
05-06 08:50:35.647: W/dalvikvm(3119): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab9ba8)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119): Process: com.example.notatki, PID: 3119
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at com.example.notatki.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest2(JSONParser.java:64)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at com.example.notatki.EditNoteActivity$GetNoteDetails$1.run(EditNoteActivity.java:145)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-06 08:50:35.697: E/AndroidRuntime(3119):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post the actual error you're receiving?

Comment: Java string equality can't be checked using ==, use method.equals("GET") and method.equals("POST") instead.

Comment: Looks like this is being done on the main thread and not, as you've written, on a background thread in AsyncTask. You've got a `Runnable` in `EditNoteActivity$GetNoteDetails` that is calling `JSONParser.makeHttpRequest2()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are either not writing or not using your `AsyncTask` correctly. This is my version that should do what you are attempting. I follow up with how to call this. There are a few common mistakes, such as directly calling the `doInBackground` method instead of `execute`, so this should clear anything up.

To wrap this code in an `AsyncTask`, create the following `class`:

```
public class MyJSONRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String url;
    String method;
    List<NameValuePair> params;

    public MyJSONRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.params = params;
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground(Void...) {
        makeHttpRequest(url, method, params)
    }
}
```

Now, to complete the task with no errors, do:

```
List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("noteid", "1"));
new MyJSONRequest("http://android-connection.cba.pl/get_note.php", "GET", list).execute();
```

---

Also, you should note that `if(method == "POST")` and `if(method == "POST")` will not resolve how you are expecting. You need to change these to `if(method.equals("POST"))` and `if(method.equals("GET"))`.

Comment: Um, if you actually read OP's question, he says that he is already doing this in a background thread using `AsyncTask`. This isn't true, of course, but telling him to use `AsyncTask` probably isn't any help.

Comment: @DavidWasser must have missed that. I changed my answer some to reflect those details.

Comment: Actually i'm doing it in this way and i think it's correct http://pastebin.com/9Q1Qfeai